# Automatic Multiple Image switch with different links on each IMG

Tags: html, css

#### Background:

Finding improved ways to use CSS, I came across the proposition of using image transitions for good effects.
After a few stumbles, I managed to do this with the help of some references to make a smooth transition in hover.
Now I want it automatic and with links in each picture, but I'm at a loss at the code.

#### Current JSFiddle:

None, JSFIDDLE doesn't accept IMG and I can't show there.

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="sky.jpg">
  <img class="front" src="bear.jpg">
</div>
```

```css
.container
{
  position:relative;
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.container img
{
  position:absolute;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.container img.front:hover
{
  opacity:0;
}
```

#### Problem:

This HTML-CSS works but for a single image switch (2 images) on hover, not for multiple ones automatically.

#### Need:

A change in the code which allows multiple switches using CSS and HTML only, with different links on each image.
I know there are possibilities with JQUERY and JAVACRIPT, I wish for a solution without these two.

#### Solution Code restrictions and parameters:

- No JQUERY nor JAVASCRIPT
- Multiple browser compatibility (doesn't need to be very old ones)
- Possibility of multiple links in each image switch

Many Thanks for all help provided.

Comment: Here i packed it into a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/fc3nb5rL/)**, but I don't exactly understand what you want ... multiple images in one "switch"? and where should be the links? what have you tried so far, in terms of trying to get it to "multiple image switches"?

Comment: ah you sourced externally, didn't know you could do that in JSF. So, to clarify: imagine it is a restaurant site with a marketting for 4 types of food. I want to insert on the single div the four images (in slow transition) and of course, while one is on the screen, you can click it and you go to the relevant food page. Now I have not been able to make the IMG changes automatic, so I didn't even try to make the links yet (in an hover it wouldn't work, only the hovered image would have the link, the start top image would change immediately on hover)

Answer (score 0):

Try this you have to move your cursor a slight (shake it a bit) to see the change in the link notice the change in the link http://jsfiddle.net/fc3nb5rL/1/

i used z-index instead of opacity

```
.back {
z-index:1;
 }
@-webkit-keyframes anim {
from {
    z-index:1;
}
to {
    z-index:-2;
}
}
.back:hover {
-webkit-animation:anim 5s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim2 {
from {
    z-index:1;
}
to {
    z-index:-2;
}
 }

.front:hover{
-webkit-animation:anim2 5s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks for that, but doesn't work on my FF 32, and I want literally to remove the hover, want it to be automatic (why did you use the webkit? I didn't...)

Comment: it's just that i am using chrome so.. you can add -moz- -o- etc.. so do you want the effect to be active only after hovering or it just occurs

Comment: @AlbanLusitanae Check this http://jsfiddle.net/fc3nb5rL/2/ i think this works better because the exact link appears

Comment: I want the images to keep switching by themselves (repeat infinite); when one shows something the user is interested in, he clicks the image and is taken to a website (normal img linkage, complicated here due to the image switching)

Comment: @AlbanLusitanae Do you want it to be slower? Did you check the link above?

Comment: let me get home and then I will have a look into it :)

Comment: sorry this doesn't work... still locked on hover. Again, I don't want hover (shouldn't be needed right?), I want auto changing images with individual links behind them... I'll also have a look at keyframes, that you presented...

Comment: This works with three images but there seems to be some problem with second image it disappears a bit faster http://jsfiddle.net/fc3nb5rL/4/

Comment: Hi akshay. I'm rewritting your fiddle, since you have some typos and also you have a FRONT reference class which goes nowhere in the HTML, it's not even called...

Comment: I have created [this](http://jsfiddle.net/oke1Lwzw/) fiddle and tidy it up for you to see where all goes wrong. You have ANIMs defined which are not called, two on BACK class one of THIRD class. All images call BACK... Z-Index I don't even know what's going on there... also added FF support code. Can you check and see if you can get it to work (it doesn't).

Comment: @AlbanLusitanae Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61571/discussion-between-akshay-and-alban-lusitanae).